# Application doesn't enter thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, serversocket

i'm trying to create a chat application using multhitreading functionalities and here's the code of the session class that handles connections and of the server class that accept connections:

Session class:

```
public class Session extends Thread{

Socket Sock;
BufferedReader din;
PrintWriter dout;
Thread receive;
Server serv;
boolean connected = false;
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public Session(Socket s, Server n){

    super("ThreadSessions");
   this.Sock = s;
   this.serv = n;

}

public void run(){
    try{
    din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Sock.getInputStream()));
    dout = new PrintWriter(Sock.getOutputStream());
    connected = true;
    Receive();

    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    receive.start();
}

public void sendTo(String text){
    dout.write(text);
    dout.flush();
}

public void sendToAll(String text){
    for(int ind = 0; ind < serv.sessions.size(); ind++){
        Session s = serv.sessions.get(ind);
        s.sendToAll(text);
    }
}

public void Receive(){
    receive = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            receive = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                String msgIn;
                    public void run() {

                        while(connected){
                        try{
                            msgIn = din.readLine(); 

                            if(msgIn != "" || msgIn != null){

                            System.out.println(msgIn);
                            msgIn = "";
                            }else{

                            }

                        }
                        catch(SocketException exc){
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       }
                    } 
            });
        }

  });
 }
}
```

Server class:

```
public class Server {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtPort;
JTextArea textArea, textSessions;

String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

ServerSocket ServSock;
Socket Sock;
String port;
public JTextField textField;
int numbSess = 0, actSess = 0;
ArrayList<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
boolean shouldRun = true;



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Server window = new Server();
    window.frame.setVisible(true);
}


   public Server() {
    initializeComponents(); //This void initializes the graphic components
   }

 private void Connect(){
  port = txtPort.getText();
  int portN = 0;

   try{
    portN = Integer.parseInt(port);
     }
   catch(NumberFormatException exc)
    {
     exc.printStackTrace();
    } 


 try{

ServSock = new ServerSocket(9081);
while(shouldRun){

Sock = ServSock.accept();

String ip = Sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

Session s = new Session(Sock, this);
s.start();
sessions.add(s);    

numbSess++;

 }
 }
 catch(Exception exc){
     exc.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(3);
   }
 }


private void initializeComponents() {
    [...]

    Button btnConn = new JButton("Open Connection");
    btnConn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Connect();
        }
    });
    btnConn.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    btnConn.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    btnConn.setBounds(160, 13, 137, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnConn);
    [...]
  }
```

What i want to do is creating a chat application that can handle more connection at the same time but instead of entering the first connection(session in my app.) it continues waiting for other connections and adding those in the arrayList.
Probably the code is full of mistakes so forgive me.
If somebody knows a better way to create a server that can handle more client's connections those are welcome.
Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the issue, but `if(msgIn != "" || msgIn != null)` is always true, and can you format your post and show where the entry points are?  Currently it's a mess and is hard to know where methods start/stop and when they're called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> instead of entering the first connection(session in my app.) it continues waiting for other connections and adding those in the arrayList

This is due to how your threads are set up

Each time you make and start a session, its `run` method is called...

```
public void run()
{
    Receive();
    [...]
    receive.start();
}
```

...which in turn sets up `receive` in `Receive();`

```
public void Receive()
{
    receive = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            receive = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    //your actual code that you wanted to run
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The thread created when ran, will do one thing, set up `receive` yet again, with the code you wanted the first time

```
receive = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //your actual code that you wanted to run
    }
});
```

But after you call `Receive();`, you only called `receive.start();` once

You'll either need to call it twice, and somehow ensure that it updated in time, or just remove the excess thread

Comment: Okay just tried that and now the application functions, thanks a lot man, you are the best.

Comment: @Michele if the problem is solved, mark it as the answer so others know the question is resolved